# How can I use my site's base template for the Django admin area?

Tags: django

I know that I can override the admin template by creating a template called `admin/base.html` and writing something like:

```
<h1>Hello!</h1>
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```

However, my site has its own base template (using "content" for the content block) and I wish to use this for the admin site. In addition to the site's base HTML, I need to add the admin CSS and scripts, such as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% block stylesheet %}{% static "admin/css/base.css" %}{% endblock %}" />
```

So I would override the admin template with a template which inherits from my site's base template. However, if I define a content block in this template to insert content, it is immediately overrided by the individual admin view templates. Changing the block name seems like the wrong solution, as the fact that it is used for the admin templates suggests that it is the correct convention used in Django.

Answer (score 0):

The good practice is to copy the original admin/base_site.html and make adjustments here (editing the title, the branding, adding `{% block extrahead %}` or `{% block extrastyle %}` with your own css/js etc.

The admin site is not expected to be integrated inside a custom template, but you can easily accords the style with your own preferences.

Comment: Not as easy to set if you have header, footer, menu, tab, ... as extending own base

Answer (score -2):

Just create an **admin/base.html** file, and put this inside :

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
# according base.html to the name of your base layout file
```

Comment: CSS and JS are hardcoded in the admin base template. If you want to replace the admin layout, the only solution is to extends your base layout and reinject manually the CSS/JS from admin base template.